# Difference between printf("%c",*(*(ptr+i)+x)) and printf("%s",*(*(ptr+i)+x))

Tags: c, pointers, printf, undefined-behavior, c-strings

I've an array of pointer, When I'm trying this C code getting an error of segmentation fault. What I'm doing wrong here?

```
  char *ptr[] = {"exam","example","testexample"};
    printf("%c\n",*(*(ptr+2)+7));
    printf("%s\n",*(*(ptr+2)+7));
```

In output of First print statement giving the expected result

```
   printf("%c\n",*(*(ptr+2)+7));
```

```
  m
```

but the second one instead of giving output of

```
  mple
```

is giving

```
   printf("%s\n",*(*(ptr+2)+7));    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: In your 2nd example you are using the character value of `'m'` as a pointer which is an invalid pointer value. Remove one `*` as `printf("%s\n",*(ptr+2)+7);`

Comment: One thing that will make it easier to understand what's happening is to remember that for any pointer `ptr` and index `i`, the expression `*(ptr + i)` is *exactly* equal to `ptr[i]`. Try to convert your pointer arithmetic expression to array indexing syntax and it should become much clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The type of the expression

```
*(*(ptr+2)+7)
```

is `char`. So the first call of `printf` is correct.

But the second call is incorrect because the format specifier `%s` expects an argument of the type `char *`. So the value of the character obtained by the expression `*(*(ptr+2)+7)` that is the character `'m'` (that for example in ASCII has the value `100`) is interpreted as an address.

In the second call just use

```
*(ptr+2)+7
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *ptr[] = { "exam", "example", "testexample" };

    printf( "%c\n", *( *( ptr + 2 ) + 7 ) );

    printf( "%s\n", *( ptr + 2 ) + 7 );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
m
mple
```

Comment: Thanks for that but can you please explain why it gives segmentation fault error?

Comment: @ArnabBhowmick *Undefined behavior!* The `"%s"` format expects a pointer to the first character of a zero-terminated array (of type `char *`). What you're passing with your shown code in the question is a single `char` element. Mismatching format specifier and argument is UB.

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude for your clarification. I got it

Answer (score 0):

Your argument `*(*(ptr+2)+7)` evaluates to *one character* with the value `'m'`, which (on an ASCII-based platform) is the same as the number 109.

When you do

```
printf("%s\n",*(*(ptr+2)+7));
```

this is *exactly the same* as

```
printf("%s\n",'m');
```

It gets compiled to machine code that loads the number 109`into a register and pushes that register on the stack. It doesn't tell`printf`anything about _where it found_ that`'m'` -- only that one raw ASCII value gets passed to the function.

`printf` then tries to interpret the 109 not as a character itself but as a *pointer* to some characters -- because that's what you asked it to do by writing `%s`. This, unsurprisingly, goes horribly wrong, since 109 is not the address of anything the program is allowed to access.

If you want to print the tail end of the string, you could instead write

```
printf("%s\n", *(ptr+2)+7 );
```

where you *don't* apply the `*` operator to the pointer you want to pass.

Comment: Your description is not necessarily true, e.g. perhaps the system uses different registers for passing pointers than for int values

Comment: @M.M: Right, in principle. But I think there's a very good chance that that is not the case on the system the OP is working on.

Answer (score 0):

*(*(ptr+2)+7) is a char value

So the first statement is correct since "%c" tells printf that first parameter is a char:

```
printf("%c\n",*(*(ptr+2)+7));
```

But in the second statement , "%s" tells printf that first parameter is (char *), that is a pointer to a char.
That way, when program executes

```
printf("%s\n",*(*(ptr+2)+7));
```

looks at the value of *(*(ptr+2)+7)  ( a char value, in this case 'm' ) as if it where a char pointer.
That is the reason of the segmentation fault.

So the corrected secon statement would be

```
printf("%s\n",*(ptr+2)+7);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the use of the expression `*(*(ptr+2)+7)` - it is hard to see what it does. That construct is used mostly by beginners who do not know C intimately yet. That is why C has a syntactic sugar for it: `*(*(ptr+2)+7)` is exactly equivalent to `ptr[2][7]`, which is the form you should be using.

Now, `ptr[2][7]` clearly is a `char`, but `%s` expects a *pointer to a `char`, the first character in a null-terminated string*, so let's pass in a *pointer to that character*:

```
printf("%s\n", &ptr[2][7]);
```